# indexOf incorrectly says that an integer isn't in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to get the index of the smallest integer in an array with the following code, but indexOf returns -1.

```
package tutorial;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class Lists {

public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] stuff = {4,3,2,1,8,4};
    int minValue = Arrays.stream(stuff).min().getAsInt(); 
    System.out.println(minValue);
    int smallestIndex = Arrays.asList(stuff).indexOf(minValue);
    System.out.println(smallestIndex);
}

}
```

Comment: Your problem is that your code is mixing up int primitive values and Integer objects.

Comment: In particular, `Arrays.asList(stuff)` is giving you a `List<Object>` containing one element, which is the array `stuff`.

Comment: So what is indexOf good for? And how can I get the index of the smallest number in the array without writing out a for loop?

Comment: The only way is to write a for loop. `indexOf` works if you already have a `List` but doesn't work so well if you try to convert primitive arrays to lists (since lists can't contain primitive types).

Comment: thank you very much